# How do I create a folder and subfolder keeping track of current year

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

The below code is boggling my mind...   what I'm trying to do here is a date check... if current date does not exist (it's 2020 and there is no 2020 folder) then create a 2020 folder. Otherwise, if it's 2019 and there is no 2020 folder, create a 2020 folder.

2nd step...  going in a folder.. it's 2020 and there is no 2020\01 - January folder … then copy last year's 12 - December into 2020\ 01 - January folder  … if it's 2019 and there is no 2020\01 - January folder, then copy this year's 12 - December into 2020\01 - January folder.

This is what I have...  but my mind is getting all jumbled trying to keep it all straight. I'm pretty sure it's the 2nd if statement that my logic might be jumbling up.

I also don't know how to test this without a new year.  =)

```
# Edited to reflect code fix as I understand it.
$arubaBuildsRootPath = "***"
$oldMonth = "12 - December"
#$year = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y"
$year = (Get-Date).year
$newMonth = "01 - January"
$newYear = $year + 1
$oldYear = $year - 1

if( -Not (Test-Path -Path $arubaBuildsRootPath\$year ) )
{
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $arubaBuildsRootPath\$year
}
Else 
{
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $arubaBuildsRootPath\$newYear
}

if( -Not (Test-Path -Path $arubaBuildsRootPath\$year\$newMonth ) )
{
    Copy-Item -Path "$arubaBuildsRootPath\$oldYear\$oldMonth\" -Destination "$arubaBuildsRootPath\$newYear\$newMonth" -recurse -Force
}
Else 
{
Copy-Item -Path "$arubaBuildsRootPath\$year\$oldMonth\" -Destination "$arubaBuildsRootPath\$newYear\$newMonth" -recurse -Force
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `$year + 1` code isn't working the way you expect... PowerShell is treating your `$year` variable as a string so the `+` is concatenating the 1 instead.

See from local tests:

```
$ (get-date -UFormat '%Y')
2019

$ (get-date -UFormat '%Y')+1
20191

$ ([int](get-date -UFormat '%Y'))+1
2020
```

So, I think if you make the `$year` variable an int, it should work as expected.

Even better (per @AnsgarWiechers comment), just use the `Year` property of the current date. No special format function needed then. This also embraces the object oriented nature of PowerShell.

```
(Get-Date).Year + 1
```

Comment: `(Get-Date).Year + 1`

Comment: thank you both.  I just got into work.  I appreciate you both for helping. =)

Comment: If I'm to understand Ansgar's suggestion.. this fix is simply this..(actually, due to formatting in comments, I'll edit my main post, let me know if I am understanding correctly.